# Getting application path in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

So in VCL, one would use the following line of code to retrieve the applications path:

```
ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)
```

I tried the same thing Firemokey and I noticed that ExeName was no longer available. What code can I use as an alternative to this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try using ParamStr(0) instead of Application.ExeName.

Comment: As far as I remember it worked. I am not able to check.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using

```
showmessage(System.SysUtils.GetCurrentDir);
```

and works like a charm :)

Comment: nope! that is wrong. what is someone sets the cur dir to something else with System.SysUtils.setCurrentDir ?

Comment: tks for your tip, I don't know this. But is not useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Android is an exception, checkout this discussion: https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=2e4a7d6e-2e78-4740-907c-a98dd8245837 and related source code:
https://gist.github.com/freeonterminate/2f7b2e29e40fa30ed3c4