# Delphi XE7 Multi Device Application - Error on EXENAME

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have trouble with getting `ExeName` of MultiDevice Application Project.

When I try to get the exename as 
`Prog_Name:= ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)`
I get error because unlike for `Vcl.Forms.Application` there is no `ExeName` property for `FMX.Forms.Application`.

How do I get `ExeName` of multidevice application?

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218979/getting-application-path-in-firemonkey

Comment: no , i read that topic!
Btw i don't understand how to solve this problems without using parameters (I'm sorry but I forgot to write it first )

Comment: That's like asking how to start your car without using your key. Why can't you use that?

Comment: Cuz in my proj paramstr is used for pass username,userpassw,dbname & ecc ecc.... :( And i can't change that!

Comment: I think  you're mistaken. Parameter 0 is just the filename. The remainder of the parameters are what you're referring to. Param 0 should not have those details.

Comment: I've just try 
Prog_Name:=  ParamStr(0); and it works !
IDK why , but before give me an ''Access Violation'',don't know why...:

--- THANKs TO WHO HAVE CORRECT MY Ans!!-- And thanks to all the community
P.S. Can i make another answ here? Cuz i've 40 minutes to wait for another 1 T_T

Comment: No. Just wait. :) (really!)

Comment: ok T_T no problem ! And thanks a lot again to all (Except GolezTrol :P )